# error : 504 Gateway Time-out nginx on

Tags: nginx

i have 400mb csv file but when i am import in to sql then its

show 504 Gateway Time-out nginx
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjJ6u.png)
user this code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gw3k.png)

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Add `set_time_limit(0);` to the top of your php.

And since you are serving pages using nginx, for your php fastcgi you will also need to change `fastcgi_timeout` to a higher value like `6000` or even higher depending on the script time